# Read JSON object from NewsApi

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react-native project where i have to display real-time news. To fetch data from news resources I am using newsAPI which gives me a JSON object as response. The sample response looks like [this](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/everything) according to newsapi.org documentation. 
 I am using fetch() method to read the response into a variable "resp". I am trying to access the parameter totalResults using `resp.totalResults` but I am getting an empty string.

Please note: Unable to connect to remote debugger for logs. Unable to figure out how the response looks. 

Tried:

(1)To print response using alert() method but receiving nothing but [object Object] 
(2) To parse the response which gives "unexpected token" error.

[image: Empty string error]

`"dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.3.10",
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.8"`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `resp` is the stream object from `fetch()` in which case you're waiting for a promise to resolve (the stream to be read) before proceeding. Once the stream has been read you can parse the response body as a json object using `.json()` which returns another promise. The data can then be handled in the next function with `.then()`.

```
fetch('test.json').then(function(response) {
  alert(response.status);
  return response.json();
}).then(function(jsonData){
  console.log(jsonData);
});
```

Comment: The API documentation says it already sends a JSON object. When I try to print the response it reads [object OBJECT]. Is there any point in parsing the resp?

Comment: `fetch()` gives you an http response which is why response.status === 200. The BODY of that response is json (as plaintext, which needs to be parsed). On your line 43 I think you could do `resp.json().then(function(data) { Alert.alert(data.totalResults); });`